# Batch script does not work properly when trying to invoke a python script

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to run a python script present in a remote server by using plink in putty. Please find my batch script below.

```
@ECHO OFF
plink -batch root@100.6.29.6 -pw eeee.. (/usr/bin/python2.6 /var/opt/anritsu/mclaw/vis/test2.py /var/opt/anritsu/mclaw/vis/ilo_ip) >>C:\vishwa\myscripts\checklist\Master_claw_check_list_ilo
plink root@100.6.29.6 -pw eeee..(cat /var/opt/anritsu/mclaw/vis/ilo_doc) >>C:\vishwa\myscripts\checklist\Master_claw_check_list_ilo
```

There is no problem in the python script . I am able to run it properly in the remote server. In the python script , I am trying to get the ILO information using python hp-module.

The python script sample is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import hpilo
import sys
import datetime
k = datetime.datetime.now()
g = open("ilo_doc","w+")
g.write('{0}\n'.format(k))
g.write("'IP ADDRESS','bios_hardware_stat','fans_stat','memory_stat','network_stat','processor_stat','storage_stat','temperature_stat'\n")
g.close()
fname = str(sys.argv[1])
with open(fname) as f:
        probe_list = f.readlines()
        for probes in probe_list:
                sys.stdout.write("Probe %s" % probes)
                probes = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in probes]
                probes = ''.join(probes)
                ilo = hpilo.Ilo('%s' %str(probes), 'root', 'elmi....')
                info1 = (ilo.get_embedded_health())
                bios_hardware_stat = info1['health_at_a_glance']['bios_hardware']['status']
                fans_stat = info1['health_at_a_glance']['fans']['status']
```

I run this script like ./test2.py ilo_ip

The output I get in my batch script is 
Probe 100.68.238.21

I don't know why I am not able to launch this script using batch.

Comment: As a work around I resolved this by using crontab in remote server. So instead of invoking the script from batch script,  I just read the output of the python script from batch. But still it would be nice if some one finds out how to do it from batch script.

Comment: When you run the batch script, what is in `C:\vishwa\myscripts\checklist\Master_claw_check_list_ilo`?

Comment: It just gives me ip address alone like "probe 100.23.24.56". It's the output from  the following line in Python script.   sys.stdout.write("Probe %s" % probes). However the Python script is not fully executed.